# addtocounter side effect

Tags: macros, tabularx, counters, multicolumn

I am trying to define the following macro:

```
\newcounter{cp}
\setcounter{cp}{1}

\newcommand{\phase}[3]{
    \multicolumn{#2}{|l|}{\makecell[l]{Phase \thecp{} - #3 JEH \\ \footnotesize{#1}}}
    \addtocounter{cp}{1}
}
```

The idea is that it is supposed to be used in a tabular block:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{10}{X|}}\hline

   [...]

   \phase{Etude de faisabilité}{6}{3}
\end{tabularx}
```

My problem is that without the

```
\addtocounter{cp}{1}
```

command, it all works fine:
[image]

But if I add this line back, it shifts the right separation bar:
[image]

Can you please help me understand why this is doing that, and how to avoid it?

Thanks a lot

Edit: here is a full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{FiraSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Fira Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
\definecolor{tableGray}{RGB}{220, 180, 180}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{cp} %compteur pour la numérotation des phases
\setcounter{cp}{1}

\newcommand{\phase}[3]{
    \multicolumn{#2}{|l|}{\makecell[l]{Phase \thecp{} - #3 JEH \\ footnotesize{#1}}}
    \addtocounter{cp}{1}
}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{10}{X|}}\hline

    \rowcolor{tableGray}
    \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Semaines} \\\hline

    \rowcolor{tableGray}
    \newcounter{c}
    \forloop{c}{1}{\value{c} < 10}%
    {%
      \thec &
    }
    \thec \\\hline

    \phase{Etude de faisabilité}{6}{3}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding a `%` to the end of this line: `\addtocounter{cp}{1}`, or better still this one: `...\footnotesize{#1}}}`.  Without you posting a full example, it is difficult to assist, since diagnosis is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Steven. I tried your solution but it did not work. Also, I added a full example as suggested.

Comment: With your MWE, I get `! LaTeX Error: Command \c@c already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comparison to the original, I placed `\newcounter{c}` in the preamble (inside the document part, but soutside of teh `tabularx` environment should also work) to get rid of the "Command \c@c already defined."  error message. Additionally, I replaced `\addtocounter{cp}{1}` with `\stepcounter{cp}` and placed this command inside of the `\multicolumn` command instead of after it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{FiraSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Fira Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
\definecolor{tableGray}{RGB}{220, 180, 180}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{cp} %compteur pour la numérotation des phases
\setcounter{cp}{1}

\newcounter{c}
\newcommand{\phase}[3]{%
    \multicolumn{#2}{|l|}{\makecell[l]{Phase \thecp{} - #3 JEH \\ \footnotesize{#1}}\stepcounter{cp}}% 
}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{10}{X|}}\hline

    \rowcolor{tableGray}
    \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Semaines} \\\hline

    \rowcolor{tableGray}
    
    \forloop{c}{1}{\value{c} < 10}%
    {%
      \thec &
    }
    \thec \\\hline

    \phase{Etude de faisabilité}{6}{3}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !